# create new table with subquery select

Tags: sql, subquery

I'm trying to create a new table from a subquery select but I get the following error: 
 Incorrect syntax near ')'.

```
SELECT * INTO foo 
FROM 
(
  SELECT DATEPART(MONTH,a.InvoiceDate) as CalMonth
        ,DATEPART(YEAR,a.InvoiceDate) as CalYear
        ,a.InvoiceDate
        ,a.StockCode
        ,a.QtyInvoiced
        ,a.Volume
  FROM sales a
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ds.CalMonth as CalMonth
        ,ds.CalYear as CalYear
        ,ds.InvoiceDate
        ,ds.StockCode
        ,ds.Cases as QtyInvoiced
        ,ds.Vol as Volume
  FROM sales1 ds
)
```

Comment: which RDBMS you are using. What exactly is the error?

Comment: In most DBMS a new table is created by using `CREATE TABLE foo AS select ... ` maybe you need to use that syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add `alias` at the end of your query.

You can do this by two methods:

**1.** If you have already created a table then you can do this using `Insert Into` like this:

```
INSERT into foo (CalMonth,CalYear,InvoiceDate,StockCode,QtyInvoiced,Volume)
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 
    DATEPART(MONTH,a.InvoiceDate) as CalMonth
    ,DATEPART(YEAR,a.InvoiceDate) as CalYear
    ,a.InvoiceDate
    ,a.StockCode
    ,a.QtyInvoiced
    ,a.Volume
FROM sales a
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    ds.CalMonth as CalMonth
    ,ds.CalYear as CalYear
    ,ds.InvoiceDate
    ,ds.StockCode
    ,ds.Cases as QtyInvoiced
    ,ds.Vol as Volume
FROM sales1 ds
) AS table1
```

For example [see this fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23780/7)

**2.** If you have not created a table then you can do this using `SELECT * INTO` like this:

```
SELECT * INTO foo from 
(
SELECT 
    DATEPART(MONTH,a.InvoiceDate) as CalMonth,
    DATEPART(YEAR,a.InvoiceDate) as CalYear,
    a.InvoiceDate,
    a.StockCode,
    a.QtyInvoiced,
    a.Volume
FROM sales a
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    ds.CalMonth as CalMonth,
    ds.CalYear as CalYear,
    ds.InvoiceDate,
    ds.StockCode,
    ds.Cases as QtyInvoiced,
    ds.Vol as Volume
FROM sales1 ds
) AS table1
```

For example [see this fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/21c9c/1)

For more reference see [SQL SERVER – Insert Data From One Table to Another Table – INSERT INTO SELECT – SELECT INTO TABLE](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/15/sql-server-insert-data-from-one-table-to-another-table-insert-into-select-select-into-table/)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
select * into foo from 
(
select 
    DATEPART(MONTH,a.InvoiceDate) as CalMonth,
    DATEPART(YEAR,a.InvoiceDate) as CalYear,
    a.InvoiceDate,
    a.StockCode,
    a.QtyInvoiced,
    a.Volume
from sales a
Union All
select 
    ds.CalMonth as CalMonth,
    ds.CalYear as CalYear,
    ds.InvoiceDate,
    ds.StockCode,
    ds.Cases as QtyInvoiced,
    ds.Vol as Volume
from sales1 ds
) as TAB
```

Just provide an `alias` to your sub queried table

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    INSERT into foo (CalMonth,CalYear, InvoiceDate,  StockCode, QtyInvoiced, Volume)
Select * From
    (select 
    DATEPART(MONTH,a.InvoiceDate) as CalMonth
    ,DATEPART(YEAR,a.InvoiceDate) as CalYear
    ,a.InvoiceDate
    ,a.StockCode
    ,a.QtyInvoiced
    ,a.Volume
    from sales a
    Union All
    select 
    ds.CalMonth as CalMonth
    ,ds.CalYear as CalYear
    ,ds.InvoiceDate
    ,ds.StockCode
    ,ds.Cases as QtyInvoiced
    ,ds.Vol as Volume
    from sales1 ds
    ) as t
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you either need to add the alias that has been suggested or (more complex) to remove the parenthesis, the `*`, the `FROM`, the second `SELECT` and move the `INTO foo`:

```
SELECT  
                                                      --- removed: FROM 
                                                      --- removed: (
                                                      --- removed: SELECT 
         DATEPART(MONTH,a.InvoiceDate) as CalMonth
        ,DATEPART(YEAR,a.InvoiceDate) as CalYear
        ,...
    INTO foo                                          --- moved

  FROM sales a
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ds.CalMonth as CalMonth
        ,...
  FROM sales1 ds ;
                                                      --- removed: )
```