# Union more than two table in sql through Python.

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to perform union over more than two tables using following query but I am getting syntax error.

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Xi(SELECT * FROM X UNION SELECT * FROM Y
UNION SELECT * FROM Z UNION SELECT * FROM W)"
```

I have also tried Insert but still getting some error.

Can someone please help me resolve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't create a new table with UNION ALL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007310/cant-create-a-new-table-with-union-all)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the table structure first and then insert the data with a sub-query.
Have a look at this post:
[create new table with subquery select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882610/create-new-table-with-subquery-select)